# Iteration running more than once per value LinkedHashMap

Tags: java, xstream

I have XStream building a Linked Hash Map for me using this xml:

```
<linked-hash-map>
 <entry>
  <string>#!/masterofsoundtrack/broadcast</string>
  <broadcast>
    <attributes class="linked-hash-set"/>
    <url>#!/masterofsoundtrack/broadcast</url>
    <name>MasterofSoundtrack</name>
    <description></description>
    <startsClosed>false</startsClosed>
  </broadcast>
 </entry>
 <entry>
  <string>MasterofSoundtrack</string>
  <broadcast reference="../../entry/broadcast"/>
 </entry>
</linked-hash-map>
```

Note: if you don't understand what XStream is supposed to do, it converts XML  to objects.  The above XML means to have a linked hash map, with two keys both pointing to the same object.

However, when I iterate through this using the following code:

```
for(Broadcast broadcast: map.getValues()){
    managers.add(new Manage(broadcast));
}
```

I am running the managers.add() line twice.  If I debug and look at the map, they have different IDs, but look identical.  Is this a bug with XStream, or something I don't understand with getValues()?

Comment: If you have two entries in your hash map, you will get two values with `HashMap#getValues`.

Comment: Why does getValues() return two pointers to the same object?  If I wanted to iterate over the entries, I would iterate over the keySet, not over the values.

Comment: Because that's how a HashMap works.  Keys are unique, there is no guarantee of uniqueness on values.  Returning just the unique values is more computationally expensive and is not general enough of a use case to be included.  If you want a unique value set, you'll have to parse it yourself (possibly with a HashSet).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
Object o = new Object;
map.put("1", o);
map.put("2", o);
System.out.print(map.values().size()) //prints 2
```

As long as the keys are unique, you will get a separate entry for each value, regardless of value equality.